# For loop to set open window on the onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a calendar of the month and I need to open a new window that let's enter different info on the `onclick` event. So I have a for loop in which I set the `onclick()` event to many divs. The title attribute holds the day of the month that was clicked.

This is my code, but no matter what day of the month I click, it's always the same one:

```
window.onload = function () {
'use strict';
var i = 0, newAppt, infoGet;

newAppt = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i = 0; i < newAppt.length; i++) {
    if (newAppt[i].getAttribute('title') !== '') {
        infoGet = newAppt[i].getAttribute('title');
        newAppt[i].addEventListener('click', newApptWin(infoGet), false);
    }
}
 };
function newApptWin(infoGet) {
'use strict';
window.open(infoGet,'test','toolbar=0');    
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs the function newApptWin(infoGet) immediate as your page loads, and it never changes. You're supposed to pass a function to the eventListener, not the result of the function (which you have done here). You can fix it like so:

```
newAppt[i].addEventListener('click', function() {newApptWin(infoGet);}, false);
```

Edit (update this is wrong):

Declare infoGet within the for loop. your entire script:

```
window.onload = function () {
'use strict';
var i = 0, newAppt;

newAppt = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i = 0; i < newAppt.length; i++) {
    if (newAppt[i].getAttribute('title') !== '') {
        var infoGet = newAppt[i].getAttribute('title');
        newAppt[i].addEventListener('click', function() {newApptWin(infoGet);}, false);
    }
}
 };
function newApptWin(infoGet) {
'use strict';
window.open(infoGet,'test','toolbar=0');    
}
```

Or you can skip infoGet completely and avoid a potential memory leak:

```
 newAppt[i].addEventListener('click', function() {newApptWin(newAppt[i].getAttribute('title'));}, false);
```

Edit 2:

```
window.onload = function () {
'use strict';
var i = 0, newAppt;

newAppt = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i = 0; i < newAppt.length; i++) {
    if (newAppt[i].getAttribute('title') !== '') {
        var infoGet = newAppt[i].getAttribute('title');
        newAppt[i].addEventListener('click', newApptWin, false);
    }
}
 };
function newApptWin() {
'use strict';
window.open(this.getAttribute('title'),'test','toolbar=0');    
}
```

Comment: When I do a console.log in the for loop I see the title attribute just fine. When I click on any of my divs the console.log gives null.What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I had the code like that before and the function tries to open 36 windows because it's been called in the for loop. And also declaring the infoGet variable in the for loop changes nothing.

Comment: please note, that I changed your addEventListener call. Try it first

Comment: This is what I get : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined"